# Shadow around a button with an image and text

Tags: android, button, shadow

I have a button, with a picture and some text:

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="42dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/text"
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/drawable"
     android:drawablePadding="-3sp"
     android:textSize="12sp"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:background="@null"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

Since my buttons are red, I want to make some shadow around them, so that you still can see them in case the picture behind them is red too.
I cannot find any approach to make the shadow only around the image and the text, it is always a square around the whole button.
The effect I want to get is the following:

Button with no shadow:

[image: button with no shadow]

Button with shadow:

[image: button with shadow]

How can I make that?

Comment: Do you have a minSdk requirement for the solution?

Comment: It would be nice if the solution was okay for minSdk 14